# How can I fix Botkit warning "debug: No handler for tick"

Tags: javascript, bots, botkit

Where can I add a handle for tick? It's quite annoying having that spam the logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do was set the debug parameter to false when instantiating a bot object.

```
var controller = Botkit.facebookbot({
    debug: false
});
```

However, if you want to see other debug statements this is the other way:

```
controller.on('tick', function(bot, event) { ... });
```